# Two versions of rails showing up when i run gem list rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

I just installed ruby and rails. When i run 'ruby -v' command it shows version of ruby that's currently installed. Similarly, I need to check the version of rails as well. Since rails was installed using RVM, the 'rails -v' command is not working. When i run the 'gem list rails' command, it shows two versions of rails. But when i try 'which rails' command, nothing happens. Please help find the version of rails installed.

Comment: try `hash -r` or `rehash` depending upon your shell.  as for the 2 versions of rails, a `gem cleanup` will get rid of the old one

Comment: How many versions of Ruby do you have installed with RVM? Try running `gem env` and `ruby -v`. Are the Ruby versions listed for each the same?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to run this into your console:

```
$ rails --version
```

Can't test from here but I'm pretty sure it was `--version` with rails.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which version a specific app is running, you can simply open Gemfile and see. Should be one of the first lines.